# Media Player on android tracing lots of info in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am playing a video in a window on titanium. I am noticing the console is outputting quite a bit of text. Several lines every second. Here is what I am seeing:

```
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 97 (msec)
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 0
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: message received msg=5, ext1=448, ext2=252
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: New video size 448 x 252
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: callback application
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: back from callback
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: getVideoWidth
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: message received msg=200, ext1=3, ext2=0
[WARN] :   MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: callback application
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: back from callback
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getVideoWidth: 448
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: getVideoHeight
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getVideoHeight: 252
[WARN] :   MediaPlayer: this is IMEDIA_PLAYER_VIDEO_EXIST
[INFO] :   MediaPlayer: sendBroadcast android.media.IMediaPlayer.videoexist
[INFO] :   MediaPlayer: Info (3,0)
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 588 (msec)
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 3
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 3, fromUser = false
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: buffering 0
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: callback application
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: back from callback
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 1140 (msec)
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 7
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 7, fromUser = false
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: mProgress = 3mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 1547 (msec)
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 9
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 9, fromUser = false
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: mProgress = 7mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: message received msg=3, ext1=11, ext2=0
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: buffering 11
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: callback application
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: back from callback
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 2107 (msec)
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 13
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 13, fromUser = false
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: mProgress = 9mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 2657 (msec)
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 16
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 16, fromUser = false
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: mProgress = 13mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: message received msg=3, ext1=11, ext2=0
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: buffering 11
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: callback application
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: back from callback
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 3075 (msec)
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 19
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 19, fromUser = false
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: mProgress = 16mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 3627 (msec)
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 22
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 22, fromUser = false
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: message received msg=3, ext1=21, ext2=0
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: buffering 21
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: callback application
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: back from callback
[TRACE] :  MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
[TRACE] :  V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 4160 (msec)
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 25
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: setProgress = 25, fromUser = false
[DEBUG] :  ProgressBar: mProgress = 22mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
```

It's all that over and over and over again. My app never did this before. I recently upgrade to Ti SDK 3.2.1 and Ti Studio: 3.2.1.201402041146

Can anyone explain this?